# Evaluating $ \int \sqrt{x^2-1} dx$

Tags: calculus

I've seen the $\sec(\theta)$ substitution, but can't I factor out an $i$ so that it becomes $i\sqrt{1-x^2}$? Then if I use the $\sin(\theta)=x$  substitution, it is comprised of only complex parts. If anyone could sort out the mistake, that'd be awesome!

Comment: @OlivierOloa the expressions in the OP's statement are equivalent: $i\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sqrt{x^2-1}$

Comment: Why is it a problem that you obtain an imaginary result? Evaluate the integrand on [-1, 1].

Answer (score 0):

The integral makes sense for $|x|\ge1$, so generally your $\theta$ will be complex and nonreal. So there's no real problem in getting a real function as the antiderivative, because the imaginary part will cancel out.

On the other hand, you will have problems in determining $\cos\theta$ given $\sin\theta$, because you have to choose the correct branch.

If you go on, you will find the usual integral, multiplied by $i$,
$$
\frac{i}{2}(\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta)=
\frac{1}{2}(i\arcsin x-ix\sqrt{1-x^2})=
\frac{1}{2}(i\arcsin x+x\sqrt{x^2-1})
$$
Note that, for $|x|>1$, $\arcsin x$ is not real. You might enjoy determining it.

Comment: Who said that $|x|<1$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Surely I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this integral with the hyperbolic cosine rather than a trigonometric function.

By-parts integration also works:

$$I:=\int\sqrt{x^2-1}dx=x\sqrt{x^2-1}-\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx.$$

Then

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\int\frac{x^2-1+1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\int\sqrt{x^2-1}\,dx+\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=I+\text{arcosh}(x),$$

and you can draw $I$.